# Proving <G\H>=G

Tags: group-theory

> Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G$. Prove that $\left<G\setminus H\right>=G$.

I get stuck when trying to write an element of $H$ in this way. Specifically we must prove:

$$\forall h \in H \forall h_1 \in H \exists n \in \mathbb{Z} \exists m \in \mathbb{Z} \exists g \in G\setminus H \colon h=h_1^ng^m$$

Or equivalently:

$$hh_1^{-n}=g^m$$

I'm not even sure whether $g^m$ is even in $H$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $H \subsetneq G$, there exists $g \in G \backslash H$. Let $h \in H$. Then $h=(hg)g^{-1}$. Now, it is easy to notice that $hg \notin H$ so that $h \in \langle G \backslash H \rangle$.

Comment: I've been misinterpreting the question when I wrote it. I thought that "$G \setminus H$" was the factor group, and that the question was asking whether $G$ can be generated with this set. This was really confusing me. Also, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For finite groups you can use the following meta-ish-argument:

The subgroup $H$ contains no more than half of the elements of $G$ (and $H$ contains half if and only if $H$ has index two), so $G\setminus H$ contains *at least* half of the elements, and does not contain the identity. As $(G\setminus H)\cup\{1\}\subseteq\langle G\setminus H\rangle$, our subgroup $\langle G\setminus H\rangle$ contains more than half of the elements of $G$. Hence, $\langle G\setminus H\rangle=G$.

This also works for subgroups of finite index in infinite groups.